# How to use grep with curl for lots of urls and return $url

Tags: curl, grep, pipe, cat

After a lot of cutting and filtering i got a list of urls, in a text file.. i want to pass these urls to a curl command to curl all the urls in the text file and at the same time, grep the output of each curled url for a word, if a match found, it'll print the url..

I tried this but it didn't work!

```
for i in $(cat crawled.txt); do 
    curl $i >> curled.txt;
    if  grep -q "form" ; then
        echo $i;
    fi
    done
```

Also if it's possible, without even using a saved txt file for urls, i want to pipe the output of an awk command into the above for loop! is that possible.

## curl

## grep

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to tell your script what to grep. You probably want `grep -q "form" curled.txt` instead of just `grep -q "form"`.

Second, if your list of URLs is not huge, you can run `curl $(cat crawled.txt) > curled.txt` (but then you can't grep `curled.txt` to list the URLs that contain `form`).

Last, here's how to pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash

curlit()
{
    while read i; do 
        curl $i >> curled.txt;
        if  grep -q "form" curled.txt; then
            echo $i;
        fi
    done
}

input()
{
    echo 1 https://stackoverflow.com
    echo 2 https://google.com
}

input | awk '{ print $2 }' | curlit
```